# Onclick event on input type image submits form

Tags: javascript, html, image, forms, form-submit

I got an input type image with a javascript onclick event attached to it.
Everytime I click the image it submits the form. I've already added the "return false", buts that that doesn't solve the problem.
Here is my code:

```
<input type="image" onclick="incrementValue(@i)" value="+" />
```

Javascript

```
function incrementValue(n) {

    var id = 'txtAantal' + n;
    var value = parseInt(document.getElementById(id).value, 10);
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value++;
    document.getElementById(id).value = value;

    var totaal = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtTotaal').value, 10);
    var prijs = parseFloat(document.getElementById('txtPrice' + n).value, 10);

    document.getElementById('txtTotaal').value = totaal + prijs;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: You need to “pass on” the return value: `onclick="return incrementValue(@i)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try returning false after running the function:

```
<input type="image" onclick="incrementValue(@i); return false;" value="+" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<input type="image" onclick="return incrementValue(@i)" value="+" />
```

Comment: The value `false` returned from the function must then be passed to the click handler for the input element.  The `onclick="return..."` does that.

Answer (score 1):

```
<button type="button" onclick="incrementValue(@i)" value="+" >                 
<img border="0" src="print.png" width="32" heigth="32" title="Click Me"/>
</button>
```

You should use a button and use type attribute like this